# Multiple TIdCmdTCPServers on same application

Tags: delphi, tcp, server, indy, indy10

I'm developing a server with many client requests. According to the type of requests, I want to use a separate `TIdCmdTCPServer` for each type of request.

In fact, it's an Accounting software that I want to separate each service with a separate `TIdCmdTCPServer`, for example one for Accounting, another one for Inventory, and so on.

Every `TIdCmdTCPServer` will have its own set of command handlers, and will be listening to its own port, but all will be activated on the same IP and running in the same application.

What is the disadvantage of this approach?

Can I use a single `TSchedulerThreadPool` shared by all of the `TIdCmdTCPServer`s? Or should I use a separate `TSchedulerThreadPool` for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you propose. The main disadvantage is just in using more system resources to maintain multiple servers in memory, and using multiple ports (which are a finite resource).  But other than for code organizational purposes, there is no real advantage over just using a single port and defining your protocol to expose multiple subsets of commands that a client can choose from.

At the very least, a single `TIdCmdTCPServer` can listen on multiple ports via its `Bindings` collection, and your command handlers can look at which port each request comes from, if needed. Or, you can switch to a standard `TIdTCPServer` and use multiple manual `TIdCommandHandlers` collections, one for each binding.

And no, you cannot share schedulers across multiple servers. Each server requires its own scheduler.  But a single server with multiple bindings needs only 1 scheduler.

Comment: Thank you @Remy . There are 2 main reasons to use this approach : 1. to organize better command-handlers, 2 : to reduce the loop counter when iterating Context list of TCPServer because I need to send message from Server to Clients, I have created a new TIdServerContextClass with a message-list for Clients as you mentioned before in SO. now I`m using 1 TIdTCPServer for sending message to clients and 3 TIdCmdTCPServer for handling commands